# Run Macro after Submitting Response in NO else Timer Complete

Tags: vba, excel

I come again with new query, I have made the Macro and assigned it on `Workbook.open`, now I want little bit changed, I want to prompt message BOX which have contains `Do You want to Stop Macro ?` Option `YES` and `NO`, If I clicked on Yes with in 10 seconds of workbook Open, I want to stay on same excel without executing the Macro; otherwise, run the macro if I clicked `NO` or if 10 seconds is completed.

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: I don't have code that is why i want the code, unable to understand how to create logic @Sixthsense

Comment: Qoute:"I want to stay on same excel without execute the Macro"  I am just asking this macro code so that we can implement the Yes/No Option in that code itself instead of creating another code and calling your current one.

Comment: maybe you can use a UserForm to do that.

Answer (score 0):

VBA has a MsgBox function, but you cannot let that one time out like you want.

To get a prompt with time-out functionality, you could use the Popup method of the WScript.Shell object.  You can create the Shell object with a CreateObject call, and see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for the Popup method for more details on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

@Dharmendra Maybe you can try this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    wbClose
End Sub

Sub wbClose()
    Dim time As Integer, prompt As String
    time = 10 'this is in seconds format
    prompt = "This Workbook will close in " & time & " seconds." & _
    vbLf & "Press OK if you want some changes to this Workbook."

    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       Select Case .Popup(prompt, time, "Message", 0)
         Case 1
            Exit Sub
       End Select
    End With
   ThisWorkbook.Close True
End Sub
```

Just do some revisions if you like. Thanks!